# Automodeler error - $_data = [];

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

I'm testing Kohana AutoModeler, but I think it is an PHP lack of knowledge.

I have just set it up and got this error `ErrorException [ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected '['` in /classes/context/user/add/factory.php.

When I open the file, Dreamweaver did not recognize this line `protected $_data = [];`  and this line `public function __construct(array $data = [])` probably because of `[]`.

In fact I did not find what is the meaning of $var = [] or how could a resolve this.

Any help you'd be appreciated

Comment: It's a shorthand for `array()`. It was introduced in PHP 5.4 if I'm not mistake. Basically, `array $data = []` is the same as `array $data = array()`. However, you have an older PHP versiont hat doesn't support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax is valid only in PHP 5.4+, in earlier versions it should be `$_data = array();`